# better quality thumbnail

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, thumbnails

I am looking c# code which creates better quality higher resolution thumbnail image.

i am having an image of dimension(600 * 900) and i  need  to create thumbnail of dimension (100 * 100) with high quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this.
I think this is what you are looking for

http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/High-Quality-Image-Resizing-with-NET.aspx

Comment: The url posted here is broken, here is the updated link: http://mikeborozdin.com/post/high-quality-image-resizing-with-net/

Answer (score 2):

Would the code in Image Resizing ( http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imgresizoutperfgdiplus.aspx licensed under the CodeProject Open License) be something of interest?
It implements various resampling filters (Hermite,Lanczos3,CatmullRom,QuadraticBSpline,...)

Answer (score -1):

You can use imagemagick http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php.
Install it and call from c# using command line.

Comment: this is not helpfull at all.
if we anted components, we would have found them ourselfs.